# Manipulating a string in a text file via PowerShell to return a specific value

Tags: string, powershell

I'm currently attempting to pull the version number out of an assemblyinfo.cs file and then append JUST the version number, 1.2.3.4, to another text file.

I've attempted to use the .split() method, but that only works if the item is already a string(from what I've read) and I pull the entirety of the string from the text file by using *select-string*

Here's what I'm working with

> $a = cat "c:\path_to_file\AssemblyInfo.cs" | select-string AssemblyVersion

Which will produce:    [assembly: AssemblyVersion("5.7.4.1")]

And then if I try to do $a.split(' " ') I will get

> Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'split'.
>   At line:1 char:21
>   + $versionstring.split <<<< (' " ')
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (split:String) [], RuntimeException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Which as I said, is due to the fact that it's considered as an Object, not a string.

The result that I want is like this though:

```
PS C:\> $a = '[assembly: AssemblyVersion("5.7.4.1")]'
$b = $a.split(' " ')
$b[2]
5.7.4.1
```

I'm assuming the issue is regarding the fact that I'm using CAT to display the contents and then pull the string, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select-String returns a MatchInfo object.  The string value of the line is in the .line property of that object

```
 $a.line.split(' " ')
```

should give you the result you're looking for.

Use

```
 $a | Get-Member
```

to see all the available properties that are returned.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR!!!!!!!!!!

That was EXACTLY what I needed!!

I'll accept the answer as soon as it let's me!